# .htaccess RewriteRule redirectinf /foo , but not /foofake

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When i use the following rule declaration:

```
RewriteRule ^foo foo.php
```

when I visit `localhost/foo` it sucessfully displayes `foo.php` , but when I visit `localhost/foofake` or `localhost/fooanythingelse`, it still displays foo.php. How to prevent this and display a 404 error page instead?

PS: I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357304/why-does-htaccess-rewriterule-foo-also-match-foobar) But what I am trying to do here is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the server to only redirect an URL that doesn't have any text following the "foo", by adding an "end string" sign (`$`).

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ foo.php
```

To make it also work for a trailing slash, add another line:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/$ foo.php
```

Comment: that works, but a trailing slash (`foo/`) leads to an error. is there any workaround for this?